# I cannot search sent emails in Gmail with Python

Tags: python, gmail, imaplib

I am trying to search for messages in the Sent (actually i care for both) but I only get incoming messages.
For the time being i have

```
imap_conn.select()
str_after = after.strftime('%d-%b-%Y')
typ, msg_ids = imap_conn.search('UTF-8','SINCE',str_after)
```

Which gives equivalent results with this

```
imap_conn.select('INBOX')
```

When I replace INBOX with ALL or SENT I get:
command SEARCH illegal in state AUTH, only allowed in states SELECTED

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Man, the error message is so misleading. What it's really saying is that you have tried to select an invalid folder name hence the search operation fails.

To verify/check the current valid folders/labels do something like:

**Using ImapClient**

```
from imapclient import IMAPClient
## Connect, login and select the INBOX
imap_conn = IMAPClient('imap.gmail.com', use_uid=True, ssl=ssl)
imap_conn.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD)

print(imap_conn.list_folders())
```

**Using imaplib**

```
import imaplib
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
mail.login('myusername@gmail.com', 'mypassword')
print(mail.list())
```

After I could see what folder names it was expecting, all was well.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you use the extra quotes in your string:

```
imap_conn.select('"[Gmail]/Sent Mail"')
```

That worked for me.

Comment: Aha, the extra quotes! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

```
import imaplib
obj = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com',993)
obj.login('userid','password')
obj.select('Sent')  # <-- response like ('OK', ['74']) --> total no. of mail in sent folder
obj.uid('SEARCH',None,'All') # <-- Returns the list of uids of the sent folder.
```

Comment: It did not work on Gmail for me so I used: imap_conn.select('[Gmail]/Sent Mail')

Comment: 'Sent' select Mails from 'Imap/Sent' folder & not from 'Gmail/Sent Mail' folder. If you Configure your gmail account in Thunderbird then it will automatically create 'Imap/Sent' Folder to place the copy of the sent mail in to that folder. if you want to select mails from 'Gmail/Sent Mail' folder then your code is ok.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use: imap_conn.select('[Gmail]/Sent Mail')

Just wanted to point this out for future users who see this. It's hidden in the comments.

Comment: Just a heads up: it seems the folder's name changes based on the language. For example for me `[Gmail]/Sent Mail` doesn't work but `[Gmail]/L&AOQ-hetetyt viestit` works (and vice versa if I change Gmail's display language from Finnish to English).

Answer (score 1):

Need to use print `imap_conn.list()`. Tags are language based. for example in spanish is `[Gmail]/Todos`