# How can I solve the error for crawling send mail data in r?

Tags: r, rjava

I tried to crawl my email data by using 'edeR' package.
I succeeded in getting 'inbox' folder, but failed to get 'sent mail'. 
Here are the codes.

```
Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME="C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_121")
library(rJava)
library(edeR)
mail_sen<-extractBetween(username="xxxx@gmail.com",
                     password="xxxxx", folder="[Gmail]/Sent Mail",
                     startDate="06-Jan-2017", endDate="06-Mar-2017", nmail=5)
```

When I change (folder="[Gmail]/Sent Mail") into (folder="inbox"), it works.
However, when I use the code above, error comes.

```
Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : 
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\lib\ext\jython.jar\Lib\imaplib.py", line 749, in uid
imaplib.error: command SEARCH illegal in state AUTH
```

I'm stuck in this error...
Anyone who can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

the error is not very informative but [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267234/i-cannot-search-sent-emails-in-gmail-with-python) suggests it means that it can't find your folder: `edeR` seems to be a wrapper around the `imaplib` Python library that is referenced in that question. According to the answers, the name of the "Sent Mail" folder is language-dependent.

So i think you might have to try different translations of "Sent Mail" in `folder="[Gmail]/Sent Mail"`

eta: i do not recommend changing your gmail language settings to see what happens to the "Sent Mail" folder name to a language you do not speak. I just spent five minutes finding out which option under the little cogwheel in gmail meant "settings" in Bahasa Indonesia.

Comment: I changed the language settings from Korean to English, and it works!!! Thank you for the nice answer:)